# Laravel/Lumen - missing commands in Artisan console

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-artisan, lumen

I have a problem with runing Laravel's Artisan. There are most of the commands missing. Everything worked fine till the last composer/code update.

For an example if I write `php artisan migrate`, I get following error: `Command "migrate" is not defined.`

Below is an example of output that I get by typing `php artisan`.

```
Laravel Framework version Lumen (5.1.6) (Laravel Components 5.1.*)

Usage:
  command [options] [arguments]

Options:
  -h, --help            Display this help message
  -q, --quiet           Do not output any message
  -V, --version         Display this application version
      --ansi            Force ANSI output
      --no-ansi         Disable ANSI output
  -n, --no-interaction  Do not ask any interactive question
      --env[=ENV]       The environment the command should run under.
  -v|vv|vvv, --verbose  Increase the verbosity of messages: 1 for normal output, 2 for more verbose output and 3 for debug

Available commands:
  help          Displays help for a command
  list          Lists commands
  serve         Serve the application on the PHP development server
 schedule
  schedule:run  Run the scheduled commands
```

Does anyone have any ideas how to fix this?

Comment: I'm not having any issues on a fresh Lumen install. Does a `composer dump-autoload` do anything for you? Also, can you show your `app/Console/Kernel.php`?

Comment: It's the same as the [original one](https://github.com/laravel/lumen/blob/master/app/Console/Kernel.php), except that it's in different namespace, but that shouldn't be a problem. At least it wasn't till now.

Comment: And it seems the problem isn't in composer because I already tried everyting, even deleting Vendor directory and reinstall everyting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems there was a problem with composer. Somehow `composer.lock` got into git ignore list and libraries used on production were different than the ones used in development.

Answer (score -2):

The syntax has changed to php artisan make:migration.

You can see a full list of commands by running php artisan list

Comment: Thank you for your input, but that is not the problem here. I didn't want `migration:make` but migrate.

And I think `php artisan` is the same as `php artisan list`. ;)